# Is incremental compilation reliable in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

As many of you already know, compiling Scala code is slow.

For continous integration purposes, a lot of time can be won, by preserving old `.class` files, and doing incremental compilation.  Deleting `.class` files is safer, but much slower.

I use SBT 0.13.9 and Scala 2.11.7 for compiling Scala/Java code.

I'd like to know if it is reliable to do incremental compilation, even when switching a git branch.

If it isn't always safe, how can it be detected?

Comment: Checked that `git checkout` uses the current timestamp, instead of the last commit time of the file.

Comment: ymmv, but in my experience, this works at least 99% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

It's safe as long as its implementation doesn't have bugs.

sbt is not bug free, so you might always encounter bugs that break the incremental compilation.

Unless you get incredibly unlucky, a bug in the sbt incremental compilation will simply result in your code base not compiling.

---

That being said, I've only encountered a bug once, when mixing a specific feature of shapeless (records) and the cake pattern.

In that specific instance, I had to manually clean some `.class` files to make the incremental compiler work again.

Answer (score 1):

Generally spoken it is reliable.

BUT the incremental compiler has it's known limitations.

For detailed information look at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Understanding-incremental-recompilation.html